# How can I enable sudo changes when my container has readOnlyRootFilesystem: true?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, containers

My Dockerfile installs sudo on my RHEL8 containers, and I'm trying to get this working  with securityContext: readOnlyRootFilesystem: true.
While the container is running, I still need to be able to make modifications to /etc/sudoers file. Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: I don't think you can. Logic tells me that placing `/etc` on a separate filesystem (other than `/`) won't work - but I have never tried that. If docker uses `initrd` you **may** be able to fudge something together - but it seems conceptually flawed to me. :)

Comment: Do you actually need sudo?  It's hard to run from applications, and you wouldn't typically try to administer a pod using `kubectl exec`.  This is doubly true in Kubernetes, where you usually have multiple replicas of a pod (and would have to make identical manual changes in all of them) and where it's possible for the cluster to delete a pod outside your control.